# Custom Claim Provider - add claims based on parameters of the request

Tags: solution, claim-provider

We have a custom claim provider, we are trying to add a option to add certian claims, based on headers/query-parameters that will be sent in the incoming request.

my issue is that i am not able to access the request in the custom claim provider,
I tried using `HttpContext.Current` but it's value is allways `null`

We use windows-identity as primary form of identification.
we use On-Prem sharepoint.

any ideas on how i can extract data out of the request and add claims based on that data?